# How can I get an expandable TextFormField in BottomNavigationBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to get an `expandableTextFormField` in `bottomNavBar` that will automatically increase in height as the user types into a new line. In my `bottomNavBar` code below, I gave the container a height of `60px` so it doesn't take up the whole screen.

```
bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
    child:  Container(
          height: 60,
          color: Colors.white,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 12,
            right: 8,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url),
                radius: 15,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 16,
                    right: 8,
                    top: 2,
                    bottom: 2,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    expands: true,
                    maxLines: null,
                    minLines: null,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                    controller: commentEditingController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Color(0x27AFAFAF),
                      hintText: 'Comment as $displayName...',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFAFAFAF)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                 
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Post',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

I also attached a screenshot for more explanation of what I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: hi henry, have you tried max-line?. and you may need to remove the height over there, if the removal of heigh attribute make  you botmnvgtionapbr fill your entire screen, try ton not use botNavAppBar and use stack instead, use align botom center to make the widget always go to bottom. and add Hot to to your question cause for a first look it look like something wrong rather then how to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my implementation

```
Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                  ),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    minHeight: 25.0,//min height you want to take by container
                    maxHeight: 100.0,//max height you want to take by container
                  ),
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                       
                      },
                      maxLines: null,
                      // focusNode: focusNode,
                      controller: _message,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13, vertical: 13),
                        hintText: "Message(optional)",
                        hintStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.white24, fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked like charm. Thanks a alot @Ruchit